# How can I get the index of a custom property?

Tags: python, scripting, properties

Is there any chance to get index of custom property ?

[image]

Thanks to batFINGER I found that you can acces custom property by:

```
import bpy
bpy.context.active_object.keys()[i] # i is index
```

but if I have array in the property i dont know how to find specific value. I used:

```
bpy.context.active_object.get(bpy.context.active_object.keys()[2][2])
```

for third value of the array but it doesnt work.

Comment: Not sure how useful a custom property index is?  Are they in same order as the `ob.keys()` list?

Comment: You cant manually use a name of property and you can add and remove property and searching the values only by for loop. I do everythink little bit responsive.

Comment: Yes but i have 36-360 properties, sometimes they are used and sometimes they are not - it depends on source data. So I would like to get the data by index, because I know the order.

Comment: View source on the custom props panel `rna_prop_ui.py`.  Can emulate the way that is ordered .

Comment: Thank you, but I am small egg for that - i am average scripter, not programmer. So if there arent some simple way I must find other solution.

Comment: If you have the `nn_` naming convention, perhaps use that with list comp.  `{p : ob[p] for p in ob.keys() if p.name.startswith("%2d_" % index)}`

Comment: Thank you that was my first thought after rna_prop_ui.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets dissect what your code does:

```
key = bpy.context.active_object.keys()[2]
# key contains the name '02_back'

char = key[2]
# gets the third character which is '_'

bpy.context.active_object.get(char)
# which throws an error as key '_' does not exist
```

It should be

```
bpy.context.active_object.get(bpy.context.active_object.keys()[2])[2]
```

Let's dissect this

```
key = bpy.context.active_object.keys()[2]
# key contains the name '02_back'

prop = bpy.context.active_object.get(key)
# gets the property with the name '02_back'

value = prop[2]
# gets the third item of the property `1.2`
```

Comment: The order of the props in the UI is sorted and filtered (doesn't list `_RNA_UI` key for instance that will have index after the UI prop was created).  Quite often `cycles` sits in index 0.   IMO relying on `keys()[2]` to be the one in position 2 is a slippery slope.

Comment: Agree I just repeated what the question was using.

Comment: Yes, you are right batFinger, but I am glad that there are explain the basic system - that was the goal. RNA_UI and cycles property can by easily skip by your previous code.